# Is it possible to ask Mathematica to find those points $(x,y)$ at which the given function may reach its global/local extrema?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, mathematical-optimization, maximum, multivalued

I have this two-variable function $f(x,y)$ for `{x,-Pi,Pi}` and `{y,-Pi,Pi}` in which $\{a,b,c\}$ are real parameters (can be positive or negative).

`f[x_,y_]=a (Cos[x]+Cos[y])+b (Cos[2x]+Cos[2y])+c (Cos[x]Cos[y]);`

**Question** Is it possible to ask Mathematica to find those points $(x,y)$ at which the function may reach its global/local extrema?

P.S. I tried to obtain those points analytically by finding the critical points but it is still difficult to choose which one may be global extrema.

Comment: Have you tried [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) and [`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := a (Cos[x] + Cos[y]) + b (Cos[2 x] + Cos[2 y]) + c (Cos[x] Cos[y])

(* Determine where partial derivatives are zero *)
extrema = {x, y, f[x, y]} /. Solve[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] == 0, {x, y}] /. C[1] -> 0 /. C[2] -> 0 // FullSimplify
```

[image: Points of extremes]

```
(* Find minima and maxima for specific values of a, b, and c *)
minmax[aa_, bb_, cc_] := Module[{e, minima, maxima},
  e = extrema /. {a -> aa, b -> bb, c -> cc};
  minima = Select[e, #[[3]] == Min[e[[All, 3]]] &];
  maxima = Select[e, #[[3]] == Max[e[[All, 3]]] &];
  {minima, maxima}]

{minima, maxima} = minmax[10, -7, 4]

(* {{{π, π, -30}}, 
    {{-ArcTan[Sqrt[119]/5], -ArcTan[Sqrt[119]/5], 109/6}, 
     {-ArcTan[Sqrt[119]/5],  ArcTan[Sqrt[119]/5], 109/6},
     { ArcTan[Sqrt[119]/5], -ArcTan[Sqrt[119]/5], 109/6},
     { ArcTan[Sqrt[119]/5],  ArcTan[Sqrt[119]/5], 109/6}}} *)
```

**Finding solutions in general**

There are only 6 unique extrema values/forumulas:

```
(* Determine where partial derivatives are zero *)
extrema = {x, y, f[x, y]} /. Solve[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] == 0, {x, y}] // FullSimplify
(unique = FullSimplify[DeleteDuplicates[extrema[[All, 3]]], 
    Assumptions -> C[1] ∈ Integers && C[2] ∈ Integers]) // TableForm
```

[image: 6 unique extrema values]

(Note that I dropped the restriction `/. C[1] -> 0 /. C[2] -> 0`.)

The first value in `unique` is the global maximum when the following occurs:

```
Reduce[Table[unique[[1]] >= unique[[i]], {i, 2, 6}]]
```

[image: Conditions when 2 (a + b) + c is the global maximum]

In this same fashion one can determine when each unique formula is the global minimum, global maximum, local minimum, or local maximum.  It does not appear that a general solution will be short and sweet.

**Getting to know the function**

Here is some `Manipulate` code that shows the global minimum and maximum location(s) along with other points where the first partial derivatives are zero:

```
f[x_, y_, a_, b_, c_] := 
 a (Cos[x] + Cos[y]) + b (Cos[2 x] + Cos[2 y]) + c (Cos[x] Cos[y])

Manipulate[
 extrema = {x, y, f[x, y, a, b, c]} /. 
       Solve[D[f[x, y, a, b, c], {{x, y}}] == 0, {x, y}, Reals] /. 
      C[1] -> c1 /. C[2] -> c2 // FullSimplify // Quiet;
 extrema = 
  Flatten[Table[Table[extrema[[i]], {c1, -1, 1}, {c2, -1, 1}], {i,  Length[extrema]}], 2];
 extrema = Select[extrema, -π <= #[[1]] <= π && -π <= #[[2]] <= π &];
 maxima = Select[extrema, #[[3]] == Max[extrema[[All, 3]]] &];
 minima = Select[extrema, #[[3]] == Min[extrema[[All, 3]]] &];
 Show[ContourPlot[f[x, y, a, b, c], {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, ContourShading -> None],
  ListPlot[{extrema[[All, {1, 2}]], maxima[[All, {1, 2}]], minima[[All, {1, 2}]]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {LightGray, Black, Red}, 
     PlotLegends -> {"Other", "Global maximum", "Global minimum"}]],
 {{a, 6}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, -7}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b, c}]
```

[image: Contour plot indicating locations of extrema]

Comment: Partial answers:  (1) That's possible but I don't think it matters (in this case).  (2) Yes.  (3) Yes and I'll add an approach to do so.

Comment: Setting `C[1]` and `C[2]` to zero does matter after all. I'll think about that more.

Comment: Legit values for `C[1]` and `C[2]` can be found with `Table[Reduce[{-\[Pi] <= extrema[[i, 1]] <= \[Pi], -\[Pi] <= extrema[[i, 2]] <= \[Pi]}], {i, Length[extrema]}] // FullSimplify`.

Comment: Are you sure about the global maximum being at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ when at least one of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are negative?

Comment: I have another question; can we claim that none of your 6 unique extrema values can be larger than $2(\lvert a \rvert+\lvert b \rvert)+\lvert c \rvert$? or, in other words, to claim that this value is the larger value that the function $f$ can take? I guess so since this happens at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ but when I check numerically by `RegionPlot3D` the result implies that your sixth value can be larger than this value! @JimB

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is as follows.

```
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
Maximize[{a (Cos[x] + Cos[y]) + b (Cos[2 x] + Cos[2 y]) +  c (Cos[x] Cos[y]), 
x >= -Pi && x <= Pi && y >= -Pi && y <= Pi}, {x, y}];
f[1, 2, -E]
```

> `{4 + E, {x -> -\[Pi], y -> 0}}`

```
f[1.0, 2, -E]
```

> `{6.71828, {x -> 3.14159, y -> -8.54234*10^-9}}`